# "Black and white dogs": ambiguity with coordinate adjectives

Tags: grammar, adjectives, singular-vs-plural

***A black and a white dog*** means "two dogs".
***A black and white dog*** means "one dog".

Then what about ***black and white dogs***?

Does this mean two things?  "Dogs, each of black and white color" and "dogs of black and dogs of white"?

Comment: I think this is a good question.  I'm not sure why it was downvoted, let alone twice.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the plural can designate either group: (1) bicolor dogs, and (2) black dogs and white dogs.

They can be disambiguated as follows:

> black dogs and white dogs
>
> black-and-white dogs
>
> black and white brindle dogs (brindle means several colors on the same
>   dog)
>
> dogs, both black and white,...

Comment: so "white and black dogs" means two things?: "bicolor dogs" and "white dogs and black dogs, which are not bicolor?"

Comment: potentially, yes.

Comment: so you should reflect that...as it is written, its still ambiguous. But thank you very much.

Comment: did you perhaps not read (2) in the first line of my response?

Comment: I would describe *brindle* as a mottled brown color.  A dog can be brindle and white in which case the dog will have patches of white and patches of brindle (mottled/variegated brown)  but you wouldn't call a black-and-white dog a brindle. See here for a picture of a brindle:  http://www.dogocanarioclub.us/images/Andy%20de%20Cielo%20de%20Canarias5.jpg  and here's a picture of a brindle and white: http://949newsnow.com/upload/SUGAR2.jpg

Comment: Thank you for your insights, and especially for your restriction on how I would and wouldn't call a black-and-white dog. Fortunately, I was a dog breeder for 20 years and black and white dogs are either spotted or brindle, as is this: http://www.ebay.com/sch/sis.html?_nkw=CHINKS%20FANCY%20BRINDLE%20BLACK%20AND%20WHITE%20HAIR%20ON%20HAND%20TOOLED%20SILVER%20CONCHOS%20NEW&_itemId=390812123952