# There are White and black dogs

Tags: grammar

You have two dogs which are black and white, two white dogs, and two black dogs. Have the following sentences correctly distinghsed them?

1. There are white and black dogs (two white and two black only)
2. There are white and black dogs (two white and black dogs only)

Comment: You'd need to start any non-confusing structure with, "You have 6 dogs… otherwise it just becomes a maths puzzle

Comment: alternatively, you could possibly refer to 'black & white' dogs as piebald [though that is usually reserved for horses]. Note that 'black & white' as a colour-pair is rarely referred to as 'white & black' even if white is the predominant colour. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piebald) tells me you can use piebald for dogs

Comment: @Pazzo I don't agree that it's a dup of that question. The OP here seems to like to differentiate other concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, your sentence would imply that there are dogs that are white, and dogs that are black, but to be unambiguous about this, I would say:

> There are white dogs and black dogs.

For the two colour dogs, I would say:

> There are black and white dogs.

Note that black comes first when describing the colour pairing.  This is still a bit ambiguous, so you could make it clearer by hyphenating.

> There are black-and-white dogs.

To describe all the dogs at once, I would say either of these:

> There are black dogs, white dogs, and black and white dogs.
>
> There are black, white, and black and white dogs.

As part of a list like this, black and white loses its ambiguity.

[Here's a related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30786/black-and-white-dogs-ambiguity-with-coordinate-adjectives?rq=1).